# Detecting if JIT is available

Tags: c#, xamarin, jit

What would be the canonical (if any, otherwise any reliable) way of detecting if the JIT engine is available in a portable way?

For example, Xamarin.iOS does not support JIT since the iOS platform enforces [DEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Execution_Prevention). Mono is quite good at bridging the gap by interpreting most things like lambda expressions these days, but some thing are not (properly) implemented, leading to runtime exceptions that hurt performance badly.

I want to do this detection from a shared Portable Class Library, if possible.

Comment: Hmm, no, you can't use a jitter on iOS because Apple forbids it.  They won't certify the app.  Trying to discover such platform-specific details from a portable library is a non-starter, the main app needs to help.

Comment: Apple forbids it by enforcing that pages that are writable never gets to be executable (Safari being the exception). I guess it's another way of saying it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging into the Mono source code, it seems the "magic" build-time property is `FULL_AOT_RUNTIME`. For example, `System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder` is conditionally compiled based on this property being unset, meaning

```
var canJit = Type.GetType ("System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder") != null;
```

should get me what I want.

Answer (score 2):

You could try performing an operation that you know will fail on your AoT code but not on JIT (creating a type dynamically, for example) and use a try/catch block to define whether or not JIT is available.

It could be implemented like this (note that this will only fail when the linker is set to "Link All Assemblies"):

```
private static bool? _isJITAvailable = null;
public static bool IsJITAvailable()
{
    if(_isJITAvailable == null)
    {
        try
        { 
            //This crashes on iPhone
            typeof(GenericClass<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(int));
            _isJITAvailable = true;
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            _isJITAvailable = false;
        }
    }

    return _isJITAvailable.Value;
}
```

I would not do so, though. Do you really need those "better performing callbacks" to begin with? This really sounds like a premature optimization.

Comment: I don't think that catching `Exception` is the way to go since it can be literally anything, `StackOverflowException`, `OutOfMemoryException` and so on..,.

Comment: Your point is correct @Kamo. I don't remember the specific exception thrown by `MakeGenericType` in this case and I have no means to test it right now, but I'll update the answer as soon as I do

Comment: In this particular case I think it is `NotSupportedException` :)

Comment: @WilliamBarbosa Thanks, that may be a solution. I will check it when I get to the build machine next time. And yes, I need this based on measurements. Besides, the Mono interpreter seems to throw NotImplementedException for some of the ops I do.

Comment: @WilliamBarbosa The above construct works in Xamarin.iOS now, as do most lambda expressions. So the above solution no longer detects the absence of a JIT.

Answer (score 0):

Why not test the performance of the two callbacks at runtime?

If yours is slower than the platform's, use the platform's.
If the platform's is slower than yours, use yours.

Comment: Sounds a bit awkward to me. My current solution is to let the main app hint this, which is not entirely bad. I just wanted to know if there is a neater solution.